# Can injection still be an issue if all the database operations are done through Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose

Learning the basics of MongoDB, I read that [MongoDB is vulnerable to injection attacks](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/securing-mongodb-external-injection-attacks) out-of-the-box. In node, this can be prevented using the help of the module [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize). So far, so good. Now let's add [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) to the equation.

If we are using Mongoose

- Do we still need to sanitize MongoDB inputs? Should we still use mongo-sanitize along with Mongoose?
- Does Mongoose offer any explicit injection protection at all, or does the protection come from enforcing types in schemas and models?

I remember reading that Mongoose can prevent injections to some extent, but I don't know the specifics, or if it is redundant to sanitize against Mongoose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the article mentioned the problem arises when the users doesn't send a string like
'bergur' and 'myawesomepassword' but instead sends `{"$ne": null}` for usernames and passwords.

If you create a schema and define username and password as strings, then Mongoose will convert it to string and you avoid the problem.

Regarding the where injection, mongo-sanitize wouldn't help you there. The solution is simply not to ever use the $where operator

So to simply answer your question:

1. No you don't need to use mongo-sanitize
2. No explicit injection protection, the protection comes from schemas and models.