Does Mongoose prevent NoSQL injections?
I know that similar questions about the prevention of NoSQL injections exist.
One example is this answer on the StackOverflow platform:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63839225/14043571
The answer mentions that when using Mongoose, we don't need to use mongo-sanitize.
However, in another article I read that "Using ODM’s like Mongoose will not solve the issue of regex injection with the operator $regex." See:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-prevent-no-sql-injection-in-node-js-e743cf7d3771
So now I'm confused. Can I rely on Mongoose to prevent NoSQL injections?

See the comment I put to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63839225/3027266

@WernfriedDomscheit thank you! So I should use an input validator like JOI before every query, even though I use Mongoose?

@WernfriedDomscheit If I'm not mistaken, I don't use input as query condition.

And the article I references also doesn't seem to talk about query conditions? It says that stuff like await collection.findOne({
email,
password
}); may be problematic, even though we use Mongoose.
